# converting java ArrayList<Comparable> to Comparable[]

Tags: java, arraylist, comparable

I am trying to get some Comparable elements into a collection and return it as a Comparable[].

```
public Comparable[] getPerms() {
    ArrayList<Comparable> resList = new ArrayList<Comparable>();
    while(hasNext()) {
       for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
         resList.add(index[i]);
       }
       moveIndex();
    }
    Comparable[] resultArray ;//how convert resList into array
    return resultArray;
  }
```

However ,I am not sure how to get the `ArrayList<Comparable>` as a `Comparable[]`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: use list.toArray() method. `resList.toArray(param)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resList.toArray(new Comparable[resList.size()])
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
    resList.toArray(new Comparable[resList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`ArrayList#toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) method.
 `resList.toArray(new Comparable[resList.size()])` may solve you problem.For further details [please see this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-arraylist-to-arrays-in-java/)